# div appear on load, disappear on click

Tags: javascript, styles, onload

I am a newbie with javascript therefore I am requesting a little bit of help here.
Basically I have a very simple HTML page and inside it I will need a DIV to appear on window load and disappear when a user clicks on 'Close'.

At this moment, onload event works perfectly, but when I click on 'Close' the DIV is still there ( I think because windows loads again ).

Here is my javascript code:

```
function popup() {
    document.getElementById("pop_up_main").style.display = "block";
}

document.getElementById("asd").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("pop_up_main").style.display = "none";
};
```

BODY calls popup() function

```
<body onload="popup()">
```

pop_up_main is my DIV and inside it I have the anchor that needs to hide the div.

```
 <div id="pop_up_main">
    <a href="#" onclick="return false" id="asd">Close</a>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. If there is something that I've missed please let me know. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try This

function popup() {
 setTimeout(function(){
   document.getElementById("pop_up_main").style.display = "block";
},5000);

}

function hidePopup() {
  document.getElementById("pop_up_main").style.display = "none";
};





 <div id="pop_up_main" style="display:none;">
     <a href="javascript:void(null);" onClick="hidePopup()" >Close</a>
```

Comment: thanks very much for your help. The code is working properly right now. However I will need the DIV to appear after 5 seconds when window loads. Is there a way in doing this ?

Comment: @Ionut Laurentiu i updated the code for DIV to appear after 5 seconds

Comment: No, is not working after 5 seconds. It's working when window loads.

Comment: now see i just edited <div id="pop_up_main" style="display:none;">

Answer (score 0):

Check the fiddle **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/N8J9A/2/)**

```
<div id="pop_up_main">
<a href="#" onclick="return false" id="asd">Close</a>
</div>
```

and **Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("asd").onclick = function () {
document.getElementById("pop_up_main").style.display = "none";
};
```

Comment: The div should appear when window loads, so your code is not actually what I was looking for. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: @lonut laurentiu "The div should appear when window loads" by default its display is block only. what am i missing

Comment: Well you are not. I would like my div to appear after 5 seconds after window loads, thats why I would like onload function to be used.My mistake because I didnt said that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

a tag reload the page and as you said it is the problem,use something other than a tag and   style it like a :

```
cursor:pointer;
text-decoration:underline
```